# Вырезать часть строки по паттерну

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть 2 типа строк:

> " 1  15.08.2011  <b>Манчестер Сити  </b>  Суонси Сити       <font color=blue>4:0    </font>";
>
> " 2  21.08.2011  Болтон Уондерерс  <b>Манчестер Сити  </b>  <font color=blue>2:3      </font>";

Т.е. в одной - название первой команды в < b>< /b>, в другой - второй команды.
[Вот](http://www.marathonbet.com/ru/sportstatext.htm?nr5=3923&gmt=1721,561) сама страница:

Посмотрите исходный код.
Нужно с помощью `preg_match_all` с каждой строки вырезать дату `xx.xx.xxxx` название первой команды и второй (вместе с тэгом `<b></b>`, если такие присутствуют) и счёт "4:0".
Уже замахался. Помогите.

```
preg_match_all('#([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})((?:<b>)?.*(?:\s{2}<\/b>\s*)?)((?:<b>)?.*(?:\s{2}<\/b>\s*)?)<font.*>#', $games, $game);
```

Я пробовал что-то такое, но не выход из-за пробелов..

Answer (score 1):

```
$date= "(?P<date>\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4})";
$com1="(\<b\>(?P<com1>.*?)\<\/b\>|(?P<com1a>.*?)(?=<))";
$com2= str_replace("1", "2", $com1);
$count="<font[^>]*>(?P<count>.*?)<\/font>";
$str=" 15.08.2011 <b>Манчестер Сити </b> Суонси Сити <font color=blue>4:0 </font>";
$str2=" 21.08.2011 Болтон Уондерерс <b>Манчестер Сити </b> <font color=blue>2:3 </font>";
$re="/".$date."\\s+".$com1."\\s*".$com2.".*?".$count."/iu";
function show($arr) { echo $arr["date"][0]."<br/>".($arr["com1"][0]?$arr["com1"][0] : $arr["com1a"][0])."<br/>". ($arr["com2"][0]?$arr["com2"][0] : $arr["com2a"][0])."<br/>".$arr["count"][0]."<br/>"; };
preg_match_all($re, $str, $arr);
show($arr);
echo "<br/>";
preg_match_all($re, $str2, $arr);
show($arr);
```

Результат будет возвращен в именованные группы. При этом команда 1 будет либо в com1, либо в com1a. Аналогичная ситуация со второй командой. В ПШП нельзя использовать две группы с одним именем, поэтому такое ограничение.
Результат работы:

```
15.08.2011
Манчестер Сити 
Суонси Сити 
4:0

21.08.2011
Болтон Уондерерс 
Манчестер Сити 
2:3
```

**upd** Увеличил наглядность результата.